# issue about spaces between words in value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9z4j/5/).

I have trouble appending an input box to a div element.

Is there a way to get the whole phrase (e.g "Option 1") to go inside the double quotes of the value attribute?

Firebug shows that the word after the space ("1" in this example) goes outside the quotes like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="Option" 3>
```

But I want it to be:

```
<input type="radio" value="Option 3">
```

HTML:

```
<div id="post_text"></div>
<select multiple>
    <option value="A">Option 1</option>
    <option value="B">Option 2</option>
    <option value="C">Option 3</option>
    <option value="D">Option 4</option>
    <option value="E">Option 5</option>
    <option value="F">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var post_text = $('#post_text');

$("select").multiselect({
    selectedText: "# of # selected",
    click: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.checked) {
            var span = '<input type="radio" value='+ ui.text +'><div id="' + ui.value + '">'+ ui.text +'</div>'
            post_text.append(span);
        } else {
            post_text.find('#'+ui.value).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use quotes, just like the rest of your attributes.  `value="'+ ui.text +'"` This is identical to the way you wrote your `id` attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the attribute:

```
var span = '<input type="radio" value="'+ ui.text +'"> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

James has the right answer, but here's an alternative. I always try to work with values and attributes directly with javascript, rather than building a big string, for exactly this reason:

So instead of:

```
var span = '<input type="radio" value='+ ui.text +'><div id="' + ui.value + '">'+ ui.text +'</div>'
post_text.append(span);
```

maybe consider:

```
var $input = jQuery("<input>").attr("type", "radio").val(ui.text);
var $div = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("id", ui.value).html(ui.text);
post_text.append($input).append($div);
```

This way you don't have to think about mixing single and double quotes, or escaping out quotes in the content, or any of that - the javascript functions (jQuery's `attr`, `val`, and `html` functions) do all that for you.